# C++ stl pop doesn't return

Tags: c++, stl

I have experienced, that the stl pop function doesn't return anything.

How can I return the top element of my stack and delete it?

The top function is not a good solution, because it returns only a reference of the top element...

Comment: How is `top` returning a reference stopping you from doing what you need to do?

Comment: because i want to delete the element, and after that the reference will not be correct!

Comment: @chris he said its not a good solution (and it isn't, in a good design), not that he can't.

Comment: *How can I return the top element?* `top()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need the element anymore after popping it just

```
// use element with
container.top();
// remove it
container.pop();
```

Otherwise make a copy of the object:

```
Element e = container.top();
container.pop(); // remove it
// feel free to use e, you made a copy of it
```

If you need to really `delete` it manually then you are not using any kind of smart pointer, which moves the problem to another topic.

Comment: Element e = container.top();
it does not make a copy, but saves only the reference of it. after I delete it, i can't get the element.

Comment: Incorrect, a copy of the element is placed into `e`. If the stack contains a pointer type then a copy of the address (which is still a copy) is placed inside `e`. But if that's the case it will still be valid after `pop()`. You still have to explain if you are storing pointers or values inside the collection.

Comment: you mean that: T toReturn = s1.top();
 s1.pop();
 return toReturn; i become an error, because s1.top() delete the element and the reference is not correct!

Comment: Your example makes a copy of the object pointed by the reference, so it will be valid after the `pop()`. You don't store the reference itself in `toReturn`, but a copy of the referenced value.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine member functions `top()` and `pop()`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main()
{
   std::stack<int> s( std::stack<int>::container_type { 1, 2, 3 } );

   while ( !s.empty() )
   {
      int x = s.top();
      s.pop();
      std::cout << x << ' ';
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
3 2 1
```

In this example the element that is in the top of the stack is copied in variable x, that is v ariable x will contain a copy of the element.