# retrieving pointer to object from stack

Tags: c++

I have problem with a stack of pointers. I have stack of pointers named ob1

```
stack<object*> ob1;
```

then I create some pointer to object and pushed into stack. when I want retrieve these pointer from stack
I use this method;

```
object * tag;
tag = new object();
tag = ob1.pop();
```

but I get "`error C2440: cannot convert void to object*`"
I am confuse what is wrong.
I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do with this code. What is `tag = new object()` for? You leak it immediately. Furthermore, `ob1.pop()` does not return a value (hence the error). Which book are you using to learn C++? Which reference are you using to look up standard library tools and functions?

Comment: I just looking a method for poping pointer from stack. but I don't know HOW? I am beginner.

Comment: If all you want to do is pop an element from the stack, just simply write `ob1.pop();` — nothing more than that. If you want to do something you haven't told me, you'll need more code ... and you'll need to explain better what you want to do. Again, which book and reference are you using? It's hard to believe that these things are not explained therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ stl pop doesn't return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552830/c-stl-pop-doesnt-return)

Comment: I am going to use those pointer, for example showing some field of object to screen. I use tag as interface. for example after poping, I am going to use cout<< tag->getData()<<endl;. I am not using specific book. this is a method from friend.

Comment: Use the stack's `top()` method to access the topmost element before popping it.

Comment: @Rommel ignore that friend--they are either playing with you or they don't know what they're doing--[and get a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because pop doesn't return anything.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/), the return type is `void`, nothing.
You'll need the `top ()` member to get the element.
N.B. pop () will call the destructor of your element.

Comment: This isn't a good question to answer. That's not that your answer is wrong, but that OP's code is so broken that the compiler error is the least of their worries.

Comment: Can't deny that... Lookup the dutch word 'rommel' in google translate...